# Darboux sums inequality with relation to Sup|f'(x)|

Tags: calculus

Assuming f is continuous on [a,b] and differential on (a,b)

and assuming f ' is bounded on (a,b) ; denote k = sup(|f '|)

prove that, for all P a partition of [a,b]:

0 ≤ U(f,P) - L(f,P) ≤ k(b-a)Δ(P)

where Δ(P) is defined as the maximal length of any interval of the partition P

and U(f,P) = Σ Mk(Xk - Xk-1) for Mk = sup(f) for x ∈ (X_k-1 , Xk)

U(f,P) = Σ mk(Xk - Xk-1) for mk = inf(f) for x ∈ (Xk-1 , Xk)

---

I tried, and am not sure if alright:

f is continuous on [a,b] then let t = max(f) and s = min(f)

then U(f,P) - L(f,P) ≤ ∑ (t-s)(Xk - Xk-1) = (t-s)(b-a)

now for any interval (Xk-1 , Xk) ⊆ [a,b]

(t-s)/(Xk - Xk-1) = f ’(c) for c ∈ [a,b]

then |f ’(c)| ≤ k

((t-s)/Δ(P))(b-a) ≤ k(b-a) and since Δ(P) is positive this completes the proof (no need for the greater than zero part here)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please google "Mathjax Stackexchange" to learn how to properly format equations on this site. You will have a hard time attracting good answers if you question is painful to read.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $f$ is an integrable real-valued function on the interval $[a,b]$ and $m$, $M$ are in $R$ such that $m$ <= $f(x)$ <= $M$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ then $m(b-a)$ <= integral of f(x) dx from a to b <= $M(b-a)$